# How to convert daytime to day in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-formatting, date-conversion

I have the following table :

```
DayTime
1 days 19:55:00
134 days 15:34:00
```

How to convert the Daytime to fully day? Which mean the hours will change to day(devide by 24)

Comment: Have you looked at the python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module? In particular the timedelta object and strptime method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `Timedeltas` to numerical units of time by dividing by units of `Timedelta`. For instance,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'DayTime':['1 days 19:55:00', '134 days 15:34:00']})
df['DayTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['DayTime'])
days = df['DayTime'] / pd.Timedelta(hours=24) 
print(days)
```

yields

```
0      1.829861
1    134.648611
Name: DayTime, dtype: float64
```

---

Note that above I'm assuming that 1 day = 24 hours. That's not always exactly true. Some days are 24 hours + 1 [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) long.

Answer (score 0):

Without using pandas and in python 2.7 (python 3 timedeltas can be directly divided):

```
import re
from datetime import timedelta

def full_days(day_time):
    d, h, m, s = map(int, re.split('\D+', day_time))
    delta = timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s)
    return d + delta.total_seconds() / timedelta(days=1).total_seconds()

print full_days('1 days 19:55:00')
print full_days('0 days 43:55:00')
print full_days('134 days 15:34:00')
```

Outputs:

```
1.82986111111
1.82986111111
134.648611111
```